# How To User jRuby as default engine on Windows without RVM?

Tags: windows, rvm, jrubyonrails

I'm developing a project with Ruby on Rails and my operating system is Windows 7. Some point I had to use a java .jar library for handling some works. I've searched a lot but I couldn't find a way how I can do that.

I've installed jRuby standalone. But when I entered 'ruby -v' on console, I still see ruby. Also I can enter 'jruby -v' and it shows jRuby version correctly. However I couldn't integrate them.

Since RVM doesn't run on Windows, I couldn' say 'rvm use' etc. I basically wanted to do [that](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/moving-an-existing-rails-app-to-run-on-jruby).

How can I do that and use .jar files in my Ruby On Rails project on Windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to run the entire rails app in jruby. I would suggest you run your current app with https://github.com/jruby/jruby-lint to look for any conflicts. After you have your app jruby compliant, you can run rails via

```
   jruby -S rails server
```

To require your jar file

```
    require 'java'
    require 'path/to/mycode.jar'
```

Always prepend any rails or rake commands with the `jruby -S` command

Comment: Running entire app in jRuby is the only way, indeed. I've tried some other things but they didn't work at all. Thanks for answer.

Answer (score 0):

[Pik](https://github.com/vertiginous/pik) is like RVM, but for Windows. That might answer part of your question.

Comment: I've tried Pik but it doesn't work for me. When switching from ruby to jruby and entering 'ruby -v' in console, its output is jruby version value while I'm waiting it to write ruby version still.

Comment: I've been waiting for someone else to answer, because I don't know for sure -- but I think if you want to use a jar in your Rails app, it's probably best to just run the whole app in JRuby. Hopefully someone who really knows will chime in.